# How to restore data that was backed up in C#?

Tags: c#, backup

How to restore data that was backed up in C#? I am trying to figure out how to restore data that was already saved. I think I figured out how to save the data, but when my application was running, I had trouble restoring the data, and I really need help with that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Lab09_E00988190
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Student> listOfStudents;
        int intCurrentStudent = 0;

        string fileName;
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        StreamWriter inputFile;
        BinaryFormatter studentFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listOfStudents = new List<Student>();
            txtGPA.Enabled = false;
            txtID.Enabled = false;
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            btnNext.Enabled = false;
            btnRegisterStudent.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnNewStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtGPA.Text = "";
            txtID.Text = "";

            txtName.Enabled = true;
            txtGPA.Enabled = true;
            txtID.Enabled = true;
            txtName.Focus();

            btnRegisterStudent.Enabled = true;
            btnNewStudent.Enabled = true;
        }

       private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            intCurrentStudent++;
            displayCurrent();
            if (intCurrentStudent == listOfStudents.Count - 1)
            {
               btnNext.Enabled = false;
            }
            btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
       }

        private void displayCurrent()
        {
            txtGPA.Text = listOfStudents[intCurrentStudent].GPA.ToString();
            txtName.Text = listOfStudents[intCurrentStudent].Name;
            txtID.Text = listOfStudents[intCurrentStudent].ID.ToString();
            lblNumberofStudents.Text =     listOfStudents[intCurrentStudent].Students.ToString();
        }

        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            intCurrentStudent--;
            displayCurrent();
            if (intCurrentStudent == 0)
            {
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            }
            btnNext.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnRegisterStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtName.Text != "")
                {
                    if (Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text) >= 0 && Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text) <= 4)
                    {
                        listOfStudents.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, txtID.Text, Int32.Parse(lblNumberofStudents.Text), Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text)));
                        txtGPA.Enabled = false;
                        txtID.Enabled = false;
                        txtName.Enabled = false;

                        if (listOfStudents.Count == 0)
                        {
                            btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                            btnNext.Enabled = false;
                        }

                        if (listOfStudents.Count == 1)
                        {
                            btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                            btnNext.Enabled = false;
                        }

                        if (listOfStudents.Count > 1)
                        {
                            btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
                            btnNext.Enabled = true;
                        }

                        if (listOfStudents.Count >= 5)
                        {
                            btnRegisterStudent.Enabled = false;
                            btnNewStudent.Enabled = false;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("GPA can't be less than 0 or greater than 4");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GPA must be in numbers!");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure you have all the right information entered there");
        }
        displaySummary();
    }

    private void displaySummary()
    {
        int numberOfStudents = 0;


        foreach (Student aStudent in listOfStudents)
        {
            numberOfStudents += aStudent.Students;
        }
        lblNumberofStudents.Text = listOfStudents.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void openFileDialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                fileName += ".txt";
            }
        }
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream inputFile = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                {
                    listOfStudents = (List<Student>)studentFormatter.Deserialize(inputFile);
                }
                if (listOfStudents.Count == 0)
                {
                    btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                    btnNext.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (listOfStudents.Count == 1)
                {
                    btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                    btnNext.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (listOfStudents.Count > 1)
                {
                    btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
                    btnNext.Enabled = true;
                }

                if (listOfStudents.Count >= 5)
                {
                    btnRegisterStudent.Enabled = false;
                    btnNewStudent.Enabled = false;
                }
                displaySummary();
                displayCurrent();
                MessageBox.Show("File backup complete!");
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to select file first!");
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "An IO exception has occured!");
            }
        }   
    }

    private void saveFileDialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                fileName += ".txt";
            }
        }
        try
        {
            using (Stream outputFile = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                studentFormatter.Serialize(outputFile, listOfStudents);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("File restoration complete!");
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "An IO exception has occured!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You should try to be specific about what you mean by "backing up" and "restoring" and try to trim down your code to the relevant lines.

Comment: What happens when you debug it and step through the code?

Comment: What kind of trouble do you have? 

Are you able to searialize a student?    

By the way: In your save-method you can provide a filter to the SaveFileDialog, so you don't have to always add .txt to the filename.